# How to call On Screen Keyboard (c:\windows\system32\osk.exe)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Can I call the application as OnScreenKeyboard on the location c:\windows\system32\osk.exe ? 
I have tried with fscommand, but failed ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is `fscommand()` present in the package `flash.system` So call it like

```actionscript
fscommand("exec", "c:\windows\system32\osk.exe");
```

This wouldn't work when you run the flash in browser due to security problems.

More details [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/package.html)

Comment: fscommand("exec", "c:\windows\system32\osk.exe");
I've tried it before, but it did not happen.... Is it necessary to adjust the flash settings?

Thanks Before

Comment: It needs that the flash file is to be made a projector. The documentation says _Executes an application from within the projector._